# Best Way to Implement Stack View in This Scenario

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, uistackview

The first ViewController that the user sees is shown below. I would like to place each row (text field + switch)into a horizontal stack view and then all eight horizontal stack views into a vertical stack view. However, I am uncertain how this would be done while keeping the labels above each text field in place. I would appreciate any advice or tips as stack views are a new concept to me and I am unsure where else to turn.

[image: this]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using UITableView. Of course using Stack view can work but it seems infeasible to add or remove a row.

Using UITableView, make your custom UITableViewCell, with the label, textfield and also the switch. To receive action from switch, can just simply using a protocol-delegate method declare in the custom UITableViewCell and implemented in your ViewController class